# Draw venn diagrams with description such as neither nor, either or...etc.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried to describe the events of venn diagrams shown in the pictures.

I came up with different ways to descirbe these two diagrams.

But English isn't my first language.

Am I right?

Or could I edit sentences to be better understood?

Thanks for your reading.

**Picture(1)**

[image]

> Picture(1) is the event that a driver either does not have liability insurance or does not have collision insurance.

**Picture(2)**

[image]

> Picture(2) is the event that a driver neither has liability insurance nor has collision insurance.

> Picture(2) is the event that a driver does not have either of liability insurance or collision insurance.

> Picture(2) is the event that a driver does not have either of the two insurance.

> Picture(2) is the event that a driver does not have either insurance.

Comment: For picture 2, 'neither nor' is what I commonly see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you should specify what your colors mean. It is not clear to me, especially since your explanations are not 100% consistent with the diagrams.

Second, as I recall (I may be wrong), ideal Venn diagrams should have a neutral background color representing neither true nor false. That reduces any confusing implications of the diagram. (I have seen some diagrams having a pale yellow background that is both visually pleasing and not distracting.)

Assuming your white means a negative condition ("NOT"), then I believe your first diagram is explained incorrectly.

Let "a" = Has Liability Insurance
Let "b" = Has Collision Insurance
Then, diagram 1 shows:
NOT (a AND b).
That is, "NOT the drivers who are insured for (both liability and collision)", rephrased as "Drivers who are not fully ensured for both liability and collision." This is my preferred statement.

You can remove "fully" or maybe just remove "both", but if you do that you make it easier to misinterpret the diagram summary.

Alternatively, by DeMorgan's Laws,
NOT (a AND b) = (NOT a) OR (NOT b)
So, diagram 1 also says, "Drivers who are NOT insured for Liability OR drivers who are NOT insured for Collision."

Comment: Is the sentence you expess "Drivers who are NOT insured for Liability OR drivers who are NOT insured for Collision." equal to the sentence in my question "A driver either does not have liability insurance or does not have collision insurance." They seem have the same logical form (NOT a) OR (NOT b).